# how to keep two ICollectionView indepedent which is from same source

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have one source which is assign to two different ICollectionView and i want to change in one ICollectionView ,but it reflect change in other ICollectionView so i doesn't want that..is there any way to do not happen like this.

Comment: `ICollectionView` can just help you manage many views with different Ordering, Filtering and Grouping. If you change some element, of course it's reflected to the underlying source as well as other views. In this case what you want is ***cloning***.

Comment: how it is used can you please tell me..

Comment: well, I think you have to make some kind of loop (even `LINQ` is some kind of loop) to clone every element. Note that normally your element may be some object, so cloning object is another topic. If each element just has some simple properties, then cloning should be easy. Anyway I would never perform any kind of cloning a collection like this if there is not any practical reason to do so.

Comment: @user3502966: please clarify what you actually want to do here. Creating new views is easy, and allows a single data source to be presented to the user in different ways (sorting, filtering, etc.). Do you want to do that? Or do you really want to actually have a second version of the _source_, such that the actual contents of the _original data_ is different in a second copy of that data?